# Spring JdbcTemplate / NamedParameterJdbcTemplate passing null value as a parameter value

Tags: spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have an issue passing a null value to NamedParameterJdbcTemplate using MapSqlParameterSource of the spring framework. Anyone knows how to do this?

Currently my code is :

```
String sql = "update person set project = :project where id = :id;";
MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
params.addValue("project ", null);
params.addValue("id ", 1);
int count = newNamedParameterJDBCTemplate().update(sql, params);
```

This is where I get a NullPointerException.

Comment: Are you set the `dataSource` for `NamedParameterJDBCTemplate` that returning from `newNamedParameterJDBCTemplate()`?

Comment: xSNRG, can you share what was the problem? Answer by Titi is same as your code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is my code on Spring 3.1

```
String sql = "update user set name = :name where id = :id";
MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
params.addValue("name", null);
params.addValue("id", 1);
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, params);
```

works fine. 
Maybe a stack trace might help?

Answer (score 13):

In pure jdbc its PreparedStatement.setNull(int,java.sql.Types.NULL);
From MapSqlParameterSource api there is

```
addValue(String paramName, Object value,int sqlType)
```

**try providing java.sql.Types.NULL as sqlType.**

May be this helps.

Answer (score 11):

There is an extra space after parameter name:

```
params.addValue("project ", null);
                        ↑   
params.addValue("id ", 1);
                   ↑
```

Answer (score 2):

### Map.of() doesn't support null

```
String sql = "update person set project = :project where id = :id;";

// ISSUE: Map.of doesn't support null values, but HashMap does:
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("project", null);
params.put("id", 1);
int count = newNamedParameterJDBCTemplate().update(sql, params);
```

Comment: thanks, helped for me )

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure if datasource is set for your jdbcTemplate like below as an example 
**namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);**

Answer (score -2):

I think semicolon is extra in code below:

```
String sql = "update person set project = :project where id = :id;";
```

Remove semicolon after id. It should be like:

```
String sql = "update person set project = :project where id = :id";
```